# Get current language with angular-translate

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

Is there a way to get the current used language in a controller (without `$translateProvider`)?

Couldn't find anything in the `$translate` service.

Comment: If for some god forsaken reason you need to use it straight in the view somewhat globally, probably the method of least effort is to define the language code in your translation provider (ie. in the actual translation file) e.g. `{ "LANG_CODE": "en" }` and use the `translate` filter in the view as usual, like: `<video controls poster="img/poster-{{ 'LANG_CODE' | translate }}.png"> […] </video>`

Comment: Why don't use $window.navigator

Answer (score 157, accepted):

`$translate.use()` is a getter and setter.

See this demo found in links of docs:

http://jsfiddle.net/PascalPrecht/eUGWJ/7/

Comment: Should I use this service only for that single feature to get current browser language? even if I'm not planning to do translations

Comment: This did not give me the current language but the default one. $translate.proposedLanguage() gave me the current used language in a controller as per the question

Answer (score 41):

`$translate.use()` is the way to go. Also, when an asynchronous loader is executed, you might wanna use `$translate.proposedLanguage()` which returns the language key of the language that is currently loaded but *not* finished loaded yet.

Comment: I was trying to determine the language before the translations were loaded but `$translate.use()` wasn't set. `$translate.proposedLanguage()` gave me the correct lang.

Comment: Is it possible to use this ``$translate.proposedLanguage()`` in app.config ?
i only have $translateProvider and i need to find the result of this function IN config, not later in controller. Do you have an idea ? Thanks a lot

Comment: + for `proposedLanguage()`

Answer (score 38):

When using angular-translate-loader-static-files I have noticed that `$translate.proposedLanguage()` returned `undefined` when using the default language while `$translate.use()` always returned the proposed language.

Therefore I fixed it by using:

```
var currentLang = $translate.proposedLanguage() || $translate.use();
```

Comment: This is the only way I get can get the current language in all situations.

Answer (score 8):

The `$translate` service has a method called `preferredLanguage()` that return what you want. The return of this function is the string of the language, like 'en'.

Here i wrote you an example:

```
angular.module('traslateApp').controller('myController', ['$scope', '$translate', function($scope,$translate){
   $scope.changeLanguage = function (langKey) {
      $translate.use(langKey);
   };
   $scope.getCurrentLanguage = function () {
       $translate.preferredLanguage();
   };
}])
```

Comment: This would give you the "preferred" language, not necessarily the "current" language selected. If you switch between languages, my understanding is that this does not do likewise.

Comment: var currentLanguage =  $translate.use(); does switch on change, as per answer by charlietfl

Answer (score 8):

`$translate.use()` seems not to work on initial load of the app, to get last selected language from storage: `$translate.storage().get(  $translate.storageKey() )`
or just
`$translate.proposedLanguage();`

Answer (score 1):

translate.currentLang is used to check the current selected language in i18n

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the better way to determine the language -

```
$window.navigator.language || $window.navigator.userLanguage
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is not related but could be useful. In angular2+ the way to access to the current language is

```
...
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
   translate.use('it');
   const currentLang = this.translate.currentLang;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private translate: TranslateService)
 {
  translate.setDefaultLang('en');
}
```