# set a variable in a function from an Angular factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-translate

I have an Angular factory that produces a function with a variable that selects an array for a dropdown. It seems that I should set that variable from a user selection in a controller. Those 2 pieces work, but I can't get the variable into the function at the controller.

The factory has several arrays and a switch() function to select one. The factory returns a function. Here's some code. ddSelections is an array.

```
languageFactories.factory('changePostDdFactory', ['$translate', function (translate) {
    return {
        withLangChoice: function (langKey) {
            //variables containing arrays and a switch() to select based on langKey
            return ddSelections;
        }
    }
}]);
```

The HTML for the button dropdown that displays the selected array is

```
<div id="postBox" class="floatingSection" data-ng-controller="postButtonController2">
  <button id="postButton" dropdown-menu="ddMenuOptions" dropdown-model="ddMenuSelected" class="btn-menu">{{ 'POST' | translate }}</button>
</div>
```

The controller for that button dropdown directive is where I am floundering. When I hardcode some things it works, though it doesn't look like "good Angular code". When its variables, I get a variety of problems. I presume I should be working with $scope, but maybe that's open to question. $scope.getCurrentLanguage seems to be the problem. Here's code.

```
residenceApp.controller('postButtonController2', ['$translate', '$scope', 'changePostDdFactory',

function ($translate, $scope, ddSelections) {
    //hardcoded works at page load and shows my intention
    //$scope.getCurrentLanguage = 'en'; //creates Scope and Model for getCurrentLanguage & ddMenuOptions
    //$scope.ddMenuOptions = ddSelections.withLangChoice($scope.getCurrentLanguage); //shows correct array from factory
    //here's my latest of many attempts with a user selected variable that is accessed via the $translate directive
    //per Batarang there is no Scope and Model for getCurrentLanguage & ddMenuOptions
    $scope.getCurrentLanguage = function ($translate) {
        alert('here I am'); //does not fire
        $translate.use(); //getter per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20444578/get-current-language-with-angular-translate
        return $translate.use(); //should return 'en' or 'es'
    };
    $scope.ddMenuOptions = ddSelections.withLangChoice($scope.getCurrentLanguage); //no dropdown, no array change
    //$scope.ddMenuOptions = ddSelections.withLangChoice(getCurrentLanguage); //page does not load
    $scope.ddMenuSelected = {};
    $scope.$watch('ddMenuSelected', function (newVal) {
        //if watch() triggers, do something
    }, true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you need to call your function?
`$scope.ddMenuOptions = ddSelections.withLangChoice($scope.getCurrentLanguage($translate));`
instead of
`$scope.ddMenuOptions = ddSelections.withLangChoice($scope.getCurrentLanguage);`

Comment: Yes, that gets the variable into the factory function on page load. For some reason, changing languages is not working for these arrays, as if $translate.use(); is not getting from $translate, but maybe that's a different problem. $translate continues to change the normal HTML. Thanks, its one step forward.